# Create V3 Json Schema that works with Json.Net Validator - Union types

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I am trying to create a schema that allows a property to be either an object or a null. Is this possible with the current JSON.NET validator? Or is my schema definitions incorrectly defined?  Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated. I narrowed by schema to express the current question.

```
Schema definition
{ "type": "object", "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema", "id": "innerobj", "additionalProperties": false, "properties": { "_id": { "type": [ "string", "null" ] } } }</value>
{ "type": "object", "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema", "id": "itemobj", "additionalProperties": false, "properties": { "name": { "type": "string" },  "inner": { "type": [ {"$ref":"innerobj", "null" ] } } }</value>
{ "type": "array", "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema", "id": "itemobjs", "items": {"$ref": "itemobj"} }</value>
{ "type": "object", "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema", "id": "outerobj", "additionalProperties": false, "properties": { "name": { "type": "string" },  "objarray": { "type": [ {"$ref":"itemobjs", "null" ] } } }</value>

Test JSON strings
{"name":"Default","objarray":null}
{"name":"Default","objarray":[{"name":"arrDefault","inner":null}]}
{"name":"Default","objarray":[{"name": "arrDefault","inner":{"_id":null}}]}
{"name":"Default","objarray":[{"name": "arrDefault","inner":{"_id":"idDefault"}}]}
```

Thanks,
Phil Doragh